# How to find out how many times a job of a gitlab-ci file has been used?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a gitlab project that contains just a `.gitlab-ci` file, with a job to execute some script that I wrote to analyze code, and I want to share that job with several people

```yaml
somejob:
  only: ["master"]
  script:
    - curl https://somegitlab/.../raw/.../analyse_code.sh
    - bash analyse_code.sh
```

To track the propagation and the use of it, I’d like to know when the file included+executed (not only static inclusion, but CI job execution)

```yaml
include:
  - project: 'my-group/my-project'
    file: '.gitlab-ci.yml'
```

Is there is any gitlab built-in way ?

Or do I need to add like a `curl`, to an API of my own, in the job, to track that this job has been executed ? But that seems hard to protect the endpoint to ensure only legimimate requests from gitlab are made, to avois someone calling it and falsing the results

Or any other suggestions ?

Thanks

Comment: There is no out of the box feature for this in gitlab. As you said either use your own api counter or you could use Gitlab project variables and use Gitlab api to access and increment the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could you GitLab's APIs to count the pipeline and job executions.

List (and therefore count) your pipeline executions with the
[Pipelines API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html#list-project-pipelines)
(use [pagination](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/rest/#pagination) wisely to optimize your implementation)